# Create a file in Android with certain permission

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-permissions

I'm developing an Android application I have to implement a function that create a folder with different files.

I wish the files in the folders were hidden, and this point is not a problem, but I want assign certain permission to files, for example I need that files are not readable / writable by user but only from application.

Also I wish the files in the folder were deleted if the application was uninstalled.

This is the code that i use to create hidden folder:

```
File JSONStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".BMA");
if (!JSONStorage.exists()) {
    if (!JSONStorage.mkdirs()) {
        Log.wtf("log: ", "Failed to create directory");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official Android documentation:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This will create file on device internal memory. This file can be read only by application. (`Context.MODE_PRIVATE`)

Comment: I wish the files were protected, so that they can not be read / modified by editor.

I wish that when you try to open the file was denied access

Comment: Well, with this setup it's actually what you get. File created with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` can be edited/read only to app itself